# Parameter cannot be used as a constant

Tags: c++, arrays

I have just finished my code, I am stuck on these last two errors:
"the value of parameter "n" cannot be used as a constant." I am using "int n" in my function to calculate average time.

```
void findavgTime(int option, int pids[], int arrivals[], int n, int bursts[], int quanta) { 

int resp[n], ta_time[n], avg_resp_time = 0, avg_ta_time = 0;
```

How should I go by this?

Comment: Use `std::vector`, as VLA extension is not standard c++.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**. So you cannot write code like:

```
int n = 10;
int arr[n];    //incorrect
```

Correct way to write this would be:

```
const int n = 10;
int arr[n];    //correct
```

For the same reason the following code is incorrect in your code as well:

```
int resp[n], ta_time[n];//incorrect because n must be a compile time constant
```

You can use `std::vector<>` for your purpose instead of using built in arrays. So instead of creating arrays you can have/create `std::vector` named `resp` and `ta_time` as follows:

```
//n denotes the size. You can also use std::vector::reserve for requesting that the vector capacity be at least enough to contain n elements
std::vector<int> resp(n); 
std::vector<int> ta_time(n);
```

Comment: nitpick: in modern C++, we'd use `constexpr` instead of `const` for compile-time constants.

Comment: Note that `const` have two meanings depending on context: In the context shown here it's a compile-time constant and can be used for arrays sizes. But if it's a class-member or a function argument then it only means "read only" and it not a compile-time constant and can't be used for e.g. array sizes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yup i am aware of that.

Comment: more nitpick: `//incorrect because n must be known at compile time` The compiler does know the value also in `int n = 10; int arr[n];` but it isnt a constant expression

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yeah i changed it to `//incorrect because n must be a compile time constant` .

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing your variable-length arrays:

> ```
> int resp[n], ta_time[n]
> ```

with modern C++ `std::vector` instances:

```
#include <vector> // for std::vector

std::vector<int> resp(n);
std::vector<int> ta_time(n);
```

You can still access vector elements using the usual `v[i]` syntax with a 0-based index, e.g.:

```
resp[2] = 100; // Access the 3rd element in the vector
```

VLAs (variable-length arrays) are *not* part of the C++ standard.
You can only create arrays with compile-time known size, e.g.

```
constexpr int n = 100; // compile-time constant
int resp[n];
```